# create variable javascript with an input value

Tags: javascript, html, variables, input

I don't know if this can be do it, i have a input with a submit:

```
Variable JSON (data/data.links)
    <input type="text" id="newVarJson" value="data" onclick="verifica();"/><br>
```

and I need to put the value of that input as the name of a variable in javascript to create a json with that name, i thought on make that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     

function verifica(){
    var document.getElementById(newVarJson).value={}
    data.value="asdf";
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}

</script>
```

As you see, the variable the input value = data, I don't know if this can be do it, so, can someone tell me any tips to make this, or it can't be do it?

Thanks!

Comment: quotes are important:  `.getElementById('newVarJson')` ; also by assigning to value it is clearing the form value  -- don't you want to read it instead?

Comment: that code it's not a child of a form, i don't use a form, only the tags input and the submit, it's a test that i need to implement into a project if it works Paul

Comment: I don't understand what " I need to put the value of that input as the name of a variable in javascript to create a json with that name" means. To create a string of json that represents a variable,  you could use `var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(myVar)`

Comment: I meant, i have an input with the value = data, so can i assign that value as name of a variable on javascript?

Comment: I edited my comment with a working code :)

Comment: and then, can i use that variable as a json, so, u understand it Paul? i don't know how to explain it better sorry

Comment: In the browser, global variables are also elements of the window[] object, so @naoxlink has the right idea although I think he needs quotes on newVarJson.  He needs something on the right hand side like window[blahblah]=0. If the text input gives the name of the variable, what do you want the value to be?

Comment: ok i explain a part of the project, with a 2 inputs, the first has the value that is used to named the json var, the second input value it's used to assign [id] into the json with the content, and a button or submit to give me the result on a div, or in an alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
window[document.getElementById(newVarJson).value];
```

and your var name will be the value of that input.

**Edit:**

```
window[document.getElementById('newVarJson').value];
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/doparibu/1/edit

Comment: `newVarJson` should be a string, since it is the ID, so you should quote it.  It is quoted in your jsbin.